# Apache - Configure Static maintenance page with 503 response for all requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have the below `RewriteRule` to redirect all the requests to `scheduledmaint.html`during site maintenance

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteRule  !^/ScheduledMaintenance/(.*)$ /ScheduledMaintenance/scheduledmaint.html  [L,R=503]
ErrorDocument 503 /ScheduledMaintenance/scheduledmaint.html
```

It works fine and `scheduledmaint.html` page is loaded successfylly but am seeing 200 response for all requests instead of 503. How do I make sure to apache returns 503 response for all requests?

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this with negative lookahead to skip image/css/js from `503`:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /ScheduledMaintenance/scheduledmaint.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!ScheduledMaintenance/|.+\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$) - [NC,L,R=503]
```